# Javascript eval() doesn't work as expected

Tags: php, javascript, json, tinymce

I'm fetching data from PHP function in JSON format.

```
 var xhReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
 xhReq.open("GET", "http://myserver/getjson", false);
 xhReq.send(null);
 var serverResponse = xhReq;

var jsondata=eval("("+serverResponse.responseText+")") //retrieve result as an JavaScript object

 images="";

 for(var i=0; i<jsondata.length;i++)
 {
  images+="  ['"+jsondata[i].title+"','"+IMAGESROOT+"121a.png"+"']";


     if(i<jsondata.length-1)
        images+=",";
 }
```

Im getting this data in following format.

```
['title 1','http://site.com/images/121a.png'],
['title 2','http://site.com/images/121a.png'],
['title 3','http://site.com/images/121a.png'],
['title 4','http://site.com/images/121a.png']
```

Finally when Im assigning this data as array using eval()

```
var tinyMCEImageList = new Array(eval(images));
```

it only show last element of array  which is `['title 4','http://site.com/images/121a.png']`.

I want every element of array to be assigned.

Comment: You should *really* be using `JSON.parse(..)` instead. Refer: http://www.json.org/js.html

Comment: Why should you assume that `eval()` will somehow parse a `JSON` into an array automatically. As @techfoobar said, it should be `JSON.parse()`

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Okay I replace eval with JSON.parse still It isn't getting my problem solved I'm still getting only last element assigned. Yet I have to used eval() function while assigning array values to veriable. other wise Im getting only '[' assign to array veriable.

Comment: Main problem is array is not properly being assigned to variable. Its showing only last element only if I use eval()

var tinyMCEImageList = new Array(eval(images));

Answer (score 2):

A simple solution would be

```
var tinyMCEImageList = eval('['+serverResponse.responseText+']');
```

or

```
var tinyMCEImageList = JSON.parse(
    '['+serverResponse.responseText.replace(/'/g, '"')+']'
);
```

But a better solution would be to generate [JSON](http://www.json.org/) by adding the missing `[` and `]` and using proper quotes, which would allow you to use `JSON.parse` directly. Note that PHP comes in standard with all the tools to [generate JSON](http://php.net/manual/en/book.json.php).

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 var tinyMCEImageList = new Array();
 for(var i=0; i<jsondata.length;i++)
{
  images+="  ['"+jsondata[i].title+"','"+IMAGESROOT+"121a.png"+"']";


 if(i<jsondata.length-1)
    images+=",";

     tinyMCEImageList[]=images
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var jsondata=eval("(["+serverResponse.responseText+"])") //retrieve result ..
```

The four elements lack array encapsulation and the last is assigned back only.

Answer (score 0):

In javascript, braces, `(` and `)`, can mean one of two things:

1. At the end of a function, it triggers a function call.
2. In an expression, it overrides operator precedence.

So, since what you're trying to eval is an expression it looks like number 2 is happening. Notice that the above two meanings are the only things that braces do in javascript. Braces cannot be used as a grouping or list operator like in Perl for example.

Next we encounter the comma operator. In javascript, commas, `,`, can mean one of four things:

1. In a function call, commas separate arguments passed into the function.
2. In an array literal, commas separate array members.
3. In an object literal, commas separate object members.
4. In an expression, a comma is a comma operator.

And what is a comma operator? A comma operator is an operator that takes two expressions, evaluates both and returns the second. So lets say you have 3 expressions X, Y and Z. The following line:

```
X, Y, Z
```

in javascript is essentially the same as:

```
(X , Y) , Z
```

so of course the above expression first evaluates X then Y and then returns Y as the result then Y and then Z and returns Z as the result.

So what you're seeing is behavior number 4: the comma acting as a comma operator.

I suspect what you intend instead is behavior number 2: for the comma to act as an array separator. If so, the string you're evaling is wrong. It should be:

```
"[" + your_string + "]"
```

Which would mean that the data you're receiving is not JSON (or rather, invalid JSON). You could fix this by doing the above to parse your non-JSON string in javascript. Or you could do the above in php to make the data valid JSON so that your javascript code would work properly.